# Using Magento just for checkout

Tags: magento, checkout

I am wondering if it is possible to use Magento just for the checkout process.

I am making an e-commerce site that has only 1 product and I plan to just display it on my home page with a "buy now" button that would populate the cart and jump straight to checkout. I realize Magento is really overkill for this task, but I like the slick checkout and integration with Paypal Website Payments Pro allowing users to stay on my site throughout. However, that is all I want to use Magento for, not the cms functions or anything else, etc.

Can this be done (if so, how) or is there a better option?

Thanks for any help,

Brian

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can! Modify the template to remove most of the page chrome and use the homepage as your single landing page. As you say, this is huge overkill, but certainly possible.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Any ideas on a better (simpler) solution? Basically, all I need is a simple checkout function and easy integration with pay pal pro...

Comment: I believe there are paid services that provide simple checkout options for simple websites, though I'd be hard pressed to name one offhand. I assume a bit of Google fu would help here.

Answer (score 0):

If you selling just 1 product why don't you use Paypal 'Add to Cart button'. Very simple and elegant solution for your need.